# Should I use "THE" in "(The) news nowadays is full of crap"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Many times I am confuse if I should use "the" or not. For example

> **News** nowadays is full of crap.
>   **The news** nowadays is full of crap.

Should I use "**the**" here (and why)?
Is there any rule of thumb?

Comment: *is* full of crap, not *are*. In this case, "The News" is singular.

Comment: Somewhat related: **[Do I need “some” in “If the weather is not so good, I read a book or some news”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75249/do-i-need-some-in-if-the-weather-is-not-so-good-i-read-a-book-or-some-news)**

Answer (score 1):

As others who have posted have stated, "The news" is better if you are expressing your discontent with the media itself: newspapers, magazines, news channels, etc.

However if you are referring to any news that you have heard from anyone, including on Facebook or Twitter or word of mouth, then just "News" is also fine. You'd basically be saying in your own words: **No news is good news.**

Comment: +1 Examples: "I have news about our upcoming journey." "He was reading the news at the time."

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to collective reports on recent or new events in a newspaper, periodical, on radio, and television, you should use "the news". (Please refer to The Free Dictionary)

The news nowadays is full of crap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's required.
"The" is omitted in a few special cases(for example, when you hear something that you find contradictory to your own knowledge or that you didn't know - "You play chess? That's news to me."), but here it's used as a singular common noun. So any rules that apply to singular common nouns apply here. Although I agree that it's a special kind of common noun, like "the sun."